# Limits using epsilon delta definition $f(x,y)=xy$ for functions of two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove: using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, the limit of both $f$ and $g$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ is $0$.

1. $f(x,y)=xy$
2. $g(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2 +y^2+1}$

Also, for Q2 can I convert $g(x,y)$ to $m(x,y)/n(x,y)=g(x,y)$ using arithmetic of limits, then prove using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition the limit of function $m$ and $n$ separately; then combine the two?

Thanks :)

---

I wonder if this is correct:
$|xy-0|<\epsilon$ given $|x-0|< \delta $ and $|y-0|< \delta $

$|xy-0|< |x-0||y-0|<\delta^2=\epsilon$

therefore: $\delta<\epsilon^{1/2}$

Comment: eddited g(x,y)....

Comment: why do you care about delta/epsilon? for function of two variable you can do by another way,for first just choose two path ,one for  x axis and second on y axis,in both case,if you go on X axis path y is equal to zero,on y axis the same x is equal to zero,so  result in both case is zero

Comment: i dont care about epsilon delta :(. my homework question does ><

Comment: Presumably he cares about delta/epsilon because it is a problem in a chapter on delta/epsilon proofs, and he is meant to apply it. @dato

Comment: yes yes  i understood,thanks

Comment: I can use the definition for simple functions...are there any general rules for using epsilon delta for multivariate?

Comment: http://mathhelpforum.com/calculus/129130-epsilon-delta-multivariable-functions.html

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090919173316AAh4lxq

Comment: thanks dato! seems i should Google more often :P

Answer (score 4):

1. First notice that 
   $$
   |x|=\sqrt{x^2}\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\|(x,y)\|_2,\ |y|=\sqrt{y^2}\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\|(x,y)\|_2 \quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2.
   $$
   Given $\varepsilon>0$, let $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. We have
   $$
   \|(x,y)\|_2\le \delta \Longrightarrow
   |f(x,y)|=|x||y|\le \|(x,y)\|_2^2 \le \delta^2=\varepsilon
   $$
2. Observe that
   $$
   |g(x,y)|=\frac{|f(x,y)|}{x^2+y^2+1}\le |f(x,y)| \quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
   $$
   and use 1.

Comment: What does the subscript "2" mean in the norm notation?

Comment: It stands for the euclidean norm (as there are many norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$, for instance $\|(x,y)\|_p=(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}$, where $p$ is a real number with $p\ge 1$).